# static in a web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to generate a very short Unique ID, in my web app, that can be used to handle sessions. Sessions, as in users connecting to eachother's session, with this ID.

But how can I keep track of these IDs? Basically, I want to generate a short ID, check if it is already in use, and create a new if it is.

Could I simply have a static class, that has a collection of these IDs? Are there other smarter, better ways to do this?

I would like to avoid using a database for this, if possible.

Comment: The only way is to use a database (no static class, no cache, nothing else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, static variables, apart from the places may be declared, will stay alive during application lifetime. An application lifetime ended after processing the last request and a specific time (configurable in web.config) as idle. As a result, you can define your variable to store Short-IDS whenever you are convenient.

However, there are a number of tools and well-known third-parties which are candidate to choose. MemCache is one of the major facilities which deserve your notice as it is been used widely in giant applications such as Facebook and others.

Based on how you want to arrange your software architecture you may prefer your own written facilities or use third-parties. Most considerable advantage of the third-parties is the fact that they are industry-standard and well-tested in different situations which has taken best practices while writing your own functions give that power to you to write minimum codes with better and more desirable responses as well as ability to debug which can not be ignored in such situations.